# Security using angularjs, login page and maintenance "Session"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, authentication

Well I am trying to build a web app with angularjs. In my webApp there is a login page aside with register page. My main problem is how to implements a login page and maintenance session with the specific user, the warning dots that came up with this scenario is when the user going to log in my web app, I will probably send a  post to the server and then will get a successful result if the user and password are okay. now during the whole application the user may use his own properties like: money, friends, age, etc... now in this situation I would like to use a session that contains all of the "data" of this specific user, but when I use angularjs, because the whole thing is on the side client, I dont think its a good idea to save the password and critical information about the user in the client side, but still i need any verify information for this user, to know that he is who is he.

I don't know how to implements this scenario good when i use angularjs, with php it may be more convenient, because there is session, which stays in the server side, and I have to worry a little bit lower than using angularjs. Can someone clear this situation?

Comment: I usually use a session cookie validated against the server for each call.

Comment: You can use a session cookie, but more better would be jwt. authentication. Google "jwt authetication", to know more

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to save classified data on the client. This data has to come from the server.
This means that the angular controller that supposed to show this data must retrieve is from the server.
You should have a service that will use $http to get this data from the server using Ajax.
  In order to retrieve the data for a specific user your client should send a token to the server that uniquely identifies the user.
This token will be sent to the client as a result of a successful login. 
The client will keep the token in a cookie or in the local storage and add it to every http request.

Comment: so the token will represent the classified data.. still doesnt solve the problem...

Comment: No. The token will be only a unique key. It will allow you to verify the credentials of the user in the server.